# General: Variables tied to other variable?

Tags: variables, keyword

I am wondering if in some programming language exists a reserved word, construct or whatever to "tie" a variable to another, e.g.:

`a = 10`
`b = a + 10`

`a = 60`

`// now b should be 70 without having to code it`

I know there might be some workarounds to do this in some programming languages, but is there any language that provides it as easily as using a keyword ?
If so, what's / 're the language(s)? how is the mechanism called?

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably code an `onChange` event handler, but I'm not aware of any predefined methods for this.